# Puppeteer : Timeout or sleep or wait inside Page.Evaluate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need a way to add some delay between clicking elements inside a page.evaluate function

below is what ive tried and it does not work

```
const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let variants = document.querySelectorAll(".item-sku-image a");


        variants.forEach(async variant => {   
           await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
           setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
           });         
            await variant.click()
        });
        return data
    });
```

Update:

the for loop below works fine for one element
when i try to use another for loop inside it - it goes crazy

```
const variants = [...document.querySelectorAll(".item-sku-image a")]; // Turn nodelist into an array
const sizes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".item-sku-size a")]; // Turn nodelist into an array

for (let variant of variants){
  // wait one second
  await new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, 1000)});
  await variant.click()
  for (let size of sizes){
   // wait one second
   await new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, 1000)});
   await size.click()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.forEach` will not work with the promises or `async...await` the way you want.

Use `for..of` instead.

```
const variants = [...document.querySelectorAll(".item-sku-image a")]; // Turn nodelist into an array
for (let variant of variants){
  // wait one second
  await new Promise(function(resolve) {setTimeout(resolve, 1000)});
  await variant.click()
}
```

It's easy to read, understand and implement.

Here are some references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/6161265

Comment: second problem for each variant elements i need to click all elements of sizes when i run another for loop inside this for loop i get some really weird behavior.

Comment: What weird behavior do you get?

Comment: first all the variants are clicked till the end - then all the sizes are clicked till the end 

it should click the first variant then click all sizes then repeat all over again (logically)